# How to write Simple UART Linux Device Driver for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c, device-driver, uart, gpio

I am a begineer in learning Device Driver.I am practising with simple example to learn device driver. Can anyone suggest me how to start writing uart ,GPIO device driver for raspberry pi,because i started practising with raspberry pi only.

Thanks in advance
Regards,
pradeep

Comment: Similar question here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8976/learning-linux-driver-development-with-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your very first driver, start with something simple.  I would take the following steps:

1. Write a simple character device driver that implements read/write/open/close file ops.  That means they can be used with 'cat' and 'echo'.
2. Based on the initial work from 1, you can write a GPIO driver.  This should be simple because all you need to do is write or read a 0 or 1 from a specific memory address.
3. Now that you have some experience with device drivers you can write a tty driver for your uart.  There are lots of examples of tty drivers in linux already.

Comment: I have written a simple Character device driver as  you said ..It works fine . Could you please send some links to write device driver for GPIO for raspberry Pi?

Comment: When i googled i got this link https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/target/linux/generic-2.6/files/drivers/char/gpio_dev.c?rev=21787   Wheather this is useful to write the driver?

Comment: There is already a GPIO driver in the kernel that you can look at. [GPIO Driver Documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/gpio/).  You can even set the direction and read/write the value using echo and cat in a shell.  See the document on sysfs.txt in the link.

Comment: ya i know already GPIO driver is there.....How to write new gpio device driver for raspberry pi?

Comment: I'm not sure what else to tell you.  You have an example of how to do it in the Linux kernel.  I recommend looking at how the existing GPIO driver is implemented and then implementing your own however you see fit.